# How to Get Tablename, constraints, foreign key and references from derby database with java?

Tags: java, reference, constraints, derby

So I have an open source piece of software written with java and the database is using Derby and it is written using hibernate.

The problem is when you go to build the latest build, there is no upgrade or migrate function to use your existing data from your current derby database into the new one.

So I am writing a java tool that will move the data over from one database to the other.

Here is the issue:  I have no problem exporting the data, the problem comes when it comes to importing the data back in because of all the foreign keys.

With help of stack overflow I did find this bit of code which gets me part of the data I need but not all that I can use.  I need to be able to create a list of  Tablenames, constraints, foreign Keys and references so that way I can add my code to alter table drop foreign keys and then import my data and then add the constraints and foreign keys and references back to the database.

```
SELECT 
fc.constraintname, 
ft.tablename, 
fs.schemaname, 
fg.descriptor, 
pc.constraintname, 
ps.schemaname 
FROM 
sys.sysconstraints fc 
JOIN sys.sysforeignkeys f ON f.constraintid =fc.constraintid 
JOIN sys.sysconglomerates fg ON fg.conglomerateid = f.conglomerateid 
JOIN sys.systables ft ON ft.tableid = fg.tableid JOIN sys.sysschemas fs ON ft.schemaid = fs.schemaid 
JOIN sys.sysconstraints pc ON pc.constraintid = f.keyconstraintid 
JOIN sys.sysschemas ps ON pc.schemaid = ps.schemaid WHERE fc.type = 'F';
```

The only thing that I can use out of this that I can parse is the Constraint and Tablename.

I still need to get the foreign key and the reference.  I do not know enough about how a derby database is laid out and I do not have time to research it and do all the cross references to find it.

So if anyone out there can help me out on what I need to do to modify the sql statement above to obtain the following in one table preferably:

Tablename - Constraint - Foreign Key - References

Example Final Result:
Cost is the tablename
constraint is 1232133
foreign key is Currency_ID
references is Currency

So I can rebuild all of the following lines similiar below:
alter table cost add constraint 1232133 foreign key (Currency_ID) references Currency

Thank You,
Shawn Mulligan

Comment: you can get everything, i.e. the table metadata via JDBC, i.e. `databaseMetaData = connection.getMetaData()` - then on the metadata you can get the tables (`databaseMetaData.getTables()` ), for each table columns, primary keys etc . See for example [here](https://www.progress.com/blogs/jdbc-tutorial-extracting-database-metadata-via-jdbc-driver) how to get everything you need